# Thread safety by way of indices in an array

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

Here is a rundown of what I am doing

```
public void Run()
{
    AnalyzeYear[] AnalyzeByYear = new AnalyzeYear[num];

    Enumerable.Range(0, num).ToList().ForEach(yr =>
    {
        AnalyzeByYear [yr] = new AnalyzeByYear (Data, yr);
    });

    Parallel.ForEach(AnalyzeYear.OfType<AnalyzeByYear>().ToList(), a =>
    {
        a.AnalyzeYear();
    });
}
```

```
public class Data()
{
    public OutputClass[,] Output { get; set; }
} 

public class PercentileCalculator
{
    public float Percentile(IEnumerable<float> seq, float percentile)
    {
        if(seq == null || seq.Count() == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        var elements = seq.ToArray();
        Array.Sort(elements);
        float realIndex = percentile * (elements.Length - 1);
        int index = (int)realIndex;
        float frac = realIndex - (float)index;
        if (index + 1 < elements.Length)
            return elements[index] * (1 - frac) + elements[index + 1] * frac;
        else
            return elements[index];
    }
}
```

```
public class AnalyzeYear
{
    private Data data;
    private int yr;

    public AnalyzeYear(int Yr, Data data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.yr = yr
    }   

    public void Analyze()
    {   
        bool done = false;
        List<float> someCalculation = new List<float>;
        float iterator = 0F;

        while(!done)
        {
            someCalculation.Add(calculation(iterator, yr, data));

            iterator = findNewIteratorValue(iterator, yr, data);

            if(weDoneYet(iterator, yr, data))
            {
                done = true;
                listOfPercentiles.ForEach( perc =>
                {
                    data.Output[yr, perc] = PercentileCalculator.Percentile(someCalculation, perc);
                });
                continue;
            }
        }
    }   
 }
```

The theory I have been working under is that although the Data variable is shared between all the threads, only the thread doing the calculation for that year can access the index of the output. Is there a glaring issue here that could cause outputs from one index to show up on another? Because I am seeing large dips in the percentiles from what I expect, and they intermittently effect either all the odd or all the even years.

The reason I included the percentile calculator is because my boss is convinced that this is the issue, and if we do the percentile calculations outside the parallel loop everything will be fine.

All places where data is used in the methods I didn't show (calculation, findNewIteratorValue, weDoneYet) every variable in data also has a year index.

When I turn off parallelization, I see that the values are calculated and stored correctly. But the code takes a hell of a lot longer to run than even the number of years times the time it took with parallelization turned on.

Comment: The idea of `Parallel.ForEach` is that you should let it [partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl) your source data automatically so that worker threads can safely work on their own subset of data without fear of contention issues.    Results should be placed into one of the new TPL bags like [`ConcurrentBag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop).  When done right you will find you don't even need `lock`s in your code

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `Analyze()`?

Comment: The assumptions and parallel code are wrong. What are you actually trying to do? Describe the problem, not the assumed solution. Calculate the nth percentile? Find the items in a specific percentile? Something else? You can use PLINQ to execute LINQ queries in parallel using appropriate parallel algorithms and partitioning for every operation like grouping, sorting, projections. Percentiles require ordering and `someList.AsParallel().OrderBy(..).ToList()` will get you a sorted list. After that, finding specific percentiles is relatively easy (depending on what you want)

Comment: Once you have a sorted list for example, the nth percentile is the item at the index location `(Count*n/100.0)`. There are `Select` and `Where` overloads that provide an item's index, so after you group and sort the data you may be able to use the index in the same PLINQ query to retrieve the correct value per group. Please post sample input and output data, so people can try to come up with a script that does what you want

Comment: @MickyD Analyze is called before any multithreading, as soon as tables are filled from the data layer.